# How to customize ternary operators in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I know how to customize binary operators, like this

```
infix operator ** { associativity left precedence 170 }
func ** (left: Double, right: Double) -> Double {
    return pow(left, right)
}
```

But, how to customize ternary operators in Swift? Can anyone give me some idea? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 21):

You *can* actually do this by declaring two separate operators that work together and using a curried function for one of the operators.

Let's declare a ternary operator `x +- y +|- z` that will check the sign of the initial value `x`, and then return the second value `y` if the sign is zero or positive and the final value `z` if the sign is negative. That is, we should be able to write:

```
let sign = -5 +- "non-negative" +|- "negative"
// sign is now "negative"
```

We'll start by declaring the two operators. The important part is to have higher precedence on the second operator - we'll evaluate that part first and return a function:

```
infix operator +- { precedence 60 }
infix operator +|- { precedence 70 }
```

Then define the functions - we'll define the second first:

```
func +|-<T>(lhs: @autoclosure () -> T, rhs: @autoclosure () -> T)(left: Bool) -> T {
    return left ? lhs() : rhs()
}
```

The important part here is that this function is curried -- if you only call it with the first two parameters, instead of returning a `T` value, it returns a `(left: Bool) -> T` function. That becomes the second parameter of the function for our first operator:

```
func +-<I: SignedIntegerType, T>(lhs: I, rhs: (left: Bool) -> T) -> T {
    return rhs(left: lhs >= 0)
}
```

And now we can use our "ternary" operator, like this:

```
for i in -1...1 {
    let sign = i +- "" +|- "-"
    println("\(i): '\(sign)'")
}
// -1: '-'
// 0: ''
// 1: ''
```

---

**Note:** I wrote a [blog post on this subject](http://natecook.com/blog/2014/10/ternary-operators-in-swift) with another example.

Comment: `func +|-` should probably use autoclosures too, so that the parameters are evaluated lazily, as with the usual `?:`. Also, while this creates something that works like a ternary operator, one cannot actually use `?` and `:` as neither of those is a valid `operator` token in swift.

Comment: I was just coming back to make that edit! And yes, `?:` itself can't be overridden.

Comment: Similar example here: http://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/2fjwav/custom_ternary_operator/

Comment: @MartinR Hadn't seen that! Just posted about this: http://natecook.com/blog/2014/10/ternary-operators-in-swift/

Comment: Minor correction: `SignedInteger` should be `SignedIntegerType` with Xcode 6.1

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, not sure how I mixed that up

Comment: Nice hack! Note that this isn't a "true" ternary operator, as you can use either `+-` or `+|-` on its own as a binary operator (assuming you provide the right operand types). But it's a pretty good substitute for not being able to create your own "real" ternary operators.

Answer (score 7):

A "true" ternary operator such as `_ ? _ : _` requires language support. Swift allows creating and customizing only unary and binary operators.

You can use the technique in @NateCook's answer to make a pair of binary operators which together work like a ternary operator, but they're still independent binary operators -- you can use either on its own. (By contrast, `_ ? _ : _` is *only* a ternary operator; `_ ? _` and `_ : _` can't be used individually.)

Of course, why stop there? You could chain more binary operators to create quaternary operators, and so on. For extra credit, try making yourself an extended spaceship operator:

```
let c: String = a <=> b
    |<| "a < b"
    |=| "a = b"
    |>| "a > b"
```

(...but please do this as an academic exercise only, or anyone else who works with code you write will hate you.)

Answer (score 3):

### Here is how you can do it in Swift 4:

```
precedencegroup SecondaryTernaryPrecedence {
    associativity: right
    higherThan: TernaryPrecedence
    lowerThan: LogicalDisjunctionPrecedence
}

infix operator ~ : SecondaryTernaryPrecedence

func ~ <T>(lhs: @autoclosure () -> Bool, rhs: @escaping @autoclosure () -> T) -> (Bool, () -> T) {
    return (lhs(), rhs)
}

infix operator >< : TernaryPrecedence

@discardableResult func >< <T>(lhs: (Bool, () -> T), rhs: @escaping @autoclosure () -> T) -> T {
    if lhs.0 {
        return lhs.1()
    } else {
        return rhs()
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```swift
let n = false ~ "it was true" >< "it was false" //"it was false"

true ~ print("it was true") >< print("it was false")
// Prints "it was true"
```

**Note:** While this is not a *true* ternary operator per se, as it uses two infix operators in conjunction with one another, it does in fact somewhat emulate its behaviour when the two operators are used together in the fashion presented above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on other answers here I made a comparison operator that has a tolerance as a third parameter.

```
precedencegroup AttachTolerancePrecedence {
    associativity: left
    higherThan: ComparisonPrecedence
    lowerThan: NilCoalescingPrecedence
}

infix operator ~== : ComparisonPrecedence
infix operator !~= : ComparisonPrecedence
infix operator ~ : AttachTolerancePrecedence

typealias CGFloatWithTolerance = (number: CGFloat?, tolerance: CGFloat)

func ~(_ f: CGFloat?, _ tolerance: CGFloat) -> CGFloatWithTolerance {
    return (number: f, tolerance: tolerance)
}

func ~==(_ g1: CGFloat?, _ g2t: CGFloatWithTolerance) -> Bool {
    // are they exactly equal (or both nil)?
    if g1 == g2t.number {
        return true
    }
    // is either of them nil?
    guard let g1 = g1, let g2 = g2t.number else {
        // both being nil was covered by the first comparison
        return false
    }
    return abs(g1 - g2) < g2t.tolerance
}

func !~=(_ g1: CGFloat?, _ g2: CGFloatWithTolerance) -> Bool {
    return !(g1 ~== g2)
}
```

Then you can use it like `if a ~== b ~ 0.001 { ... }`. It works great, but I think I'm going to roll this back and just use a regular function before my coworkers get mad at me.