# Ternary Operators For Initialisation In Swift

Tags: swift, operator-keyword, ternary

From [How to customize ternary operators in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637821/how-to-customize-ternary-operators-in-swift) I know that it's possible to create custom ternary operators using two binary operators, my question is:

**Is there a way I could use it for initialisation of classes or structs?**

Say I have a `LinearEquation`. Everything works fine but initialising an instance doesn't feel very natural. Here's how it works at the moment:

```
struct LinearEquation {
    var m: Double
    var c: Double

    func of(x: Double) -> Double {
        return m * x + c
    }
}

let f = LinearEquation(m: 2, c: 1)
f.of(2) // returns 5
```

Is there a way I could create a `LinearEquation` by writing `let f = m * x + c`? Would it also be possible to omit the `+ c` if the line passed through the origin?

(I've given an answer below but I was wondering if anyone had any other suggestions for the reason stated at the end of my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose a slightly different approach. With your solution, you
get the unexpected result:

```
let f1 = x * 2 + (1 + 2)
println(f1.of(1)) // 5.0 (correct)

let f2 = x * 2 + 1 + 2
println(f2.of(1)) // 4.0 (What ??)
```

And

```
let f3 = { println("foo") } * 2
```

compiles without making sense.

I would define the linear function "x" as a static member
(and `m`, `c` as *constant* properties):

```
struct LinearEquation {
    let m: Double
    let c: Double

    func of(x: Double) -> Double {
        return m * x + c
    }

    static let X = LinearEquation(m: 1.0, c: 0.0)
}
```

and addition and multiplication as

```
func * (lhs: LinearEquation, rhs: Double) -> LinearEquation {
    return LinearEquation(m: lhs.m * rhs, c: lhs.c * rhs)
}

func + (lhs: LinearEquation, rhs: Double) -> LinearEquation {
    return LinearEquation(m: lhs.m, c: lhs.c + rhs)
}
```

Then

```
let f1 = LinearEquation.X * 2 + 1 + 2
println(f1.of(1)) // 5.0
```

works as expected. And with

```
extension LinearEquation : FloatLiteralConvertible {
    init(floatLiteral value: Double) {
        self = LinearEquation(m: 0.0, c: value)
    }
}
```

you can define a constant function simply as

```
let f2 : LinearEquation = 2.0
println(f2.of(3)) // 2.0
```

Comment: With my answer I hadn't considered what other non-sensical results you'd get, so thanks for pointing that out! Your works perfectly though! And nice idea with the `FloatLiteralConvertible`!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use that syntax in all situations because it's not entirely clear what type `f` is. You could instead write:

```
let f: LinearEquation = m * x + c
```

It's not quite as succinct, however it makes the intentions clearer. Anyway, onto my answer!

**Firstly,** Looking at the example: if you break down the statement `f = m * x + c`, it makes sense for `m * x + c` to return a `LinearEquation` which is then assigned to `f`. The problem then becomes overloading `*` and `+` to create a `LinearEquation`:

**Secondly,** `x`, in this case, doesn't actually provide any information in the creation of a `LinearEquation`; it's just a placeholder for an `x` value that will be used later. Therefore I'll declare `x`, at global scope, like so:

```
func x() {} // Yup, does nothing!
```

**Thirdly,** you need to consider the order in which the operators are evaluated. Therefore `x * m` will be evaluated first and the `+ c` will be evaluated second. This means `x * m` could return a `LinearEquation` with no y-intercept. Then the `+` operator could take the `LinearEquation`, add the intercept and return the return the complete `LinearEquation`. Here are the operators:

```
// lhs is where you pass x, defined earlier.
func * (lhs: () -> Void, rhs: Double) -> LinearEquation {
    return LinearEquation(m: rhs, c: 0.0)
}

func + (var lhs: LinearEquation, rhs: Double) -> LinearEquation {
    lhs.c = rhs
    return lhs
}
```

**Lastly,** now you can create a `LinearEquation` like so:

```
let f = x * 2 + 1
f.of(2) // returns 5
```

Or if it passes through the origin:

```
let f = x * 2
f.of(2) // returns 4
```

The one main problem I can think of is not being able to use `x` as a variable now. So if anyone has a better solution it would be great to hear.